# Strange volume that separates objects in selectable and non-selectable items

Tags: modeling

I am facing issues with non-selectable verteces, edges and faces in edit-mode. Some faces, edges and verteces of an object are selectable other are not. All belong to the same object, there definitively noduplicate verteces (I also tried to "merge by distance"). I'd like to understand, whether this behavior is a bug or a feature.

When I toggle to wireframe or solid mode there is long and stretched volume going diagonally through the scene. Everything outside this volume is invisible and not selectable in edit mode - everything inside the volume is visible and selectable in edit mode. Whe toggling to material preview or rendering mode, the whole scenery is visible. The "cutting" volume has the shape of a spotlight that seems to come from out of space, however I don't have any objects such as sun or spot lights, the might in any way (rotation, position, etc) correspond to this "spot-light" volume.

Is this a bug or feature?

Any idea, how to recover my project in the first case and what change in the latter case?

[image: wireframe mode, showing the "cutting" volume]

[image: Same scene in material preview mode]

Thanks in advance

Boris

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have accidentally activated a *clipping region* or a *render region*. Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, or clear the regions from the View menu at the top:

[image: Clip]

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! I mixed it with Ctrl-b. No idea, what Alt-b is good for. I'll find the answer for this question in the manuals, though.

Comment: @BorisGlawe If Christopher's answer helped solving your problem you should mark it as "Accepted", to signalize others there is a working solution for this problem. Please read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)